# Java 8: Parallel stream to wait until all the threads finishes the task

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using parallel stream to large amount of files with large amount of data and write them into a particular format.
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   mergeController.compactFiles();
   mergeController.writeMergedFlag();
}
private void compactFiles() {
  Set<String> events = this.listSubDirectoryNames(inputDir);
  events.parallelStream().forEach(event -> writeEvent(event, eventSchemaMap.get(event), this.configuration));
}
```

These methods don't return anything as they are just writing the files. I am seeing `writeMergedFlag()` is being called mostly after 1.5 hr of running the process.
What is the issue here? Is it the heap space issue or something else?
I haven't encountered this type of issue before.

Comment: What's the problem / what is your expectation?

Comment: Expectation is that parallel stream finish writing all the files before moving on to next statement.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Which is what happens, and is why the "next statement" (call to `writeMergedFlag()`) doesn't happen until 1.5 hours later. It is unclear what you perceive the issue to be, since you expect it to wait, and it *is* waiting.

Answer (score 4):

I reckon it's because a parallel stream utilizes a `ForkJoinPool` which has a fixed amount of threads.  If these `writeEvent` tasks are small, I'd recommend using a cached thread pool instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    mergeController.compactFiles();
    mergeController.writeMergedFlag();
}

private void compactFiles() {
    Set<String> events = this.listSubDirectoryNames(inputDir);
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    events.forEach(event -> service.execute(() -> writeEvent(event, eventSchemaMap.get(event), configuration)));
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS); // Arbitrary value
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting. 
Yes, this utility is writing 1.5gb merged file for the total of 2TB of smaller source files.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav If that 1.5 GB file is being loaded into memory, then definitely increase your heap size as well so the JVM doesn't have to dynamically allocate it.

Comment: Source files are small in sizes, like in KBs. Utility is reading until it reaches 1.5gb and then writes it to the disk. I am making sure that resources are being closed before the next iteration. 
Is there a way to calculate the heap size based on number of threads running concurrently?

Comment: Not sure, but setting your initial heap size to 1.5 GB should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

All `parallelStream()` in JVM by default use the same `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` which has `numberOfCPUs - 1` worker threads. 
So in your case you first need to check with profiler what consumes time and if there simply a lot of files to process you can use custom thread pool for your parallel stream.

```
private void compactFiles() throws Exception {
  Set<String> events = this.listSubDirectoryNames(inputDir);
  ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(4); // you might need to adjust this value to find optimal performance
  customThreadPool.submit(() -> events.parallelStream().forEach(event -> writeEvent(event, eventSchemaMap.get(event), this.configuration))).get(); //Due to how ForkJoin pool works tasks will be submitted to the same pool which was used to execute parent task
}
```

http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool

Comment: Agree if he wants that writeMergedFlag() is called directly and don't have to wait until all writeEvents are called